# Web page throwing java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError

Tags: java

I added a couple of external Jar libraries to my project and it's giving me this error when I execute this line of code:

```
 <%
        GitlabAPI gitlabAPI = GitlabAPI.connect(url, token);
 %>
```

> root cause
>
> javax.servlet.ServletException:
>   java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/gitlab/api/GitlabAPI
>     org.apache.jasper.runtime.PageContextImpl.doHandlePageException(PageContextImpl.java:916)
>     org.apache.jasper.runtime.PageContextImpl.handlePageException(PageContextImpl.java:845)
>     org.apache.jsp.Dashboard_jsp._jspService(Dashboard_jsp.java:232)
>     org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:70)
>     javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:731)
>     org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:439)
>     org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:395)
>     org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:339)
>     javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:731)
>     org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
>   root cause
>
> java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/gitlab/api/GitlabAPI
>     com.atp.servlets.GitLabIntegration.FetchProjects(GitLabIntegration.java:14)
>     org.apache.jsp.Dashboard_jsp._jspService(Dashboard_jsp.java:178)
>     org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:70)
>     javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:731)
>     org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:439)
>     org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:395)
>     org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:339)
>     javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:731)
>     org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
>   root cause
>
> java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.gitlab.api.GitlabAPI
>     org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1892)
>     org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1735)
>     com.atp.servlets.GitLabIntegration.FetchProjects(GitLabIntegration.java:14)
>     org.apache.jsp.Dashboard_jsp._jspService(Dashboard_jsp.java:178)
>     org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:70)
>     javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:731)
>     org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:439)
>     org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:395)
>     org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:339)
>     javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:731)
>     org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)

But I have all the missing Classes. ***Even when I click alt-enter on GitlabAPI it imports the correct package.***  **Why is this throwing Class not found error??**

[image]

Comment: Try to do a Project-> Clean in Eclipse or  File -> Invalidate caches in IntelliJ,  and do a Build again.

Comment: @robot_alien didnt help.

Comment: lol. I put it on WEB-INF/lib and now it works.

Comment: ah I see! So it wasn't there in your classpath...